# Algorithm for comparisons of elements in a two dimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm

I am creating a Python program for a company that sells iPhone accessories. The program will have a function that accepts as a parameter a list of lists, where each list element contains two values that describe a product--a price and an estimated quality (an integer value). I'd like to find a case where the price of one item is lower than another but its quality is higher than the other. So for example I will pass this list to my function:

```
some_inventory = [[11.95, 10], [7.95, 12], [6.50, 3],...]
```

In this list the element [7.95, 12] will have a lower price and higher quality than [11.95, 10]. If this case exists I'd like to return a boolean value like good_deal = True.

There is about a hundred thousand of these list elements in some_inventory. I can use a brute force method to compare each price with all other prices and then check their quality against each other, but this is very slow. I tried sorting by price first and for items with the same price I'd eliminate lower quality items and just add the highest quality item to a new list (eg, if there were items with [4.50, 2], [4.50, 5], [4.50, 8] I added only [4.50, 8] to a new list). But this still seems too time-consuming.

Is there a more efficient algorithm to do these comparisons? It doesn't have to be in python, pseudocode or C/C++ is fine.

Comment: Can you be more specific with what you want this algorithm to do? How does it behave? What will it return?

Comment: @mathguy54 If a case exists where a product is cheaper than another product but has higher quality I just want the program to return a boolean value like good_deal = True. So good_deal would be set to a default value of False at the beginning.

Comment: sort by quality first then break ties with lowest price

Comment: So do you pass in a product's statistics, like `[7.80, 11]`, and your algorithm will say whether there is a product in some_inventory which has both a lower price an a higher quality? Be explicit and detailed in your specification if you please.

Comment: @padraic-cunningham wouldn't this give me the same algorithmic running time as sorting by price first then quality?

Comment: @mathguy54 I pass in the entire list with thousands of these price and quality list elements and the program has to tell me if there is a good deal or not.

Comment: So you don't actually need the statistics of the better product, just that there exists a better deal?

Comment: Yes I just want to know if this list of inventory that is getting passed into the function contains at least two items, where the first item is both cheaper and of higher quality than a second item.

Comment: If I understand correct, you want to "remove any item that is strictly worse (more expensive AND lowre quality) than a given other item". That looks like a job for Dynamic Programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def has_good_deal(deals):
    return sorted(deals) != sorted(deals, key=lambda x: list(reversed(x)))
```

The left hand side of the expression sorts the deals by their price, and if their prices are equal, by their quality. The right hand side of the expression sorts the deals by their quality, and if their qualities are equal, by their price.

If the sorts are not equal, then there are at least two deals `[p1, q1]` and `[p2, q2]` that have swapped places. If they have swapped places, `p1<p2` and `q1>q2`, which means that `[p1, q1]` is a good deal compared to `[p2, q2]`. If the sorts are equal, then there is no good deal.

Comment: I think OP wanted to find which deals are good deals, not wheter there is a good deal in the list.

Comment: @Mephy The OP states, "I just want the program to return a boolean value".

Comment: This worked perfectly! I just set good_deal = has_good_deals(deal). Can you explain a bit more about how you got this? I understand that on the left hand side in the return expression you're just sorting deals (by price I'm assuming), but what is being sorted on the right hand side?

Comment: @MNRC the interpreter is your friend, try it out, its often easier to understand than reading an explanation! You can type only parts of an expression to find out the partial results.

Comment: Ok, I think understand your code and the reasoning behind it, but would never have come up with this solution myself in a million years :P. Thanks. About that list() function on the right hand side--what does it do? I thought it just explodes a string into a list? Aren't the quality values already in a list?